# git flow with two master branches, is it possible?

Tags: git, branch, git-flow, branching-strategy

I am working in a project with a weird branching scheme. Let's say this is a shared project repository that holds a few websites (just an example below):

- http://web1
- http://web2
- http://web3
- http://web4

from the sites above web1, web2, web3 shares the same functionality, web4 shares the same as the other plus a few changes. The previous team ended building a master branch for web1, web2, web3 and a web4_master for web4. Here is an example in how the branching looks like:

```
λ git branch
* web4_master
  master
  develop
```

I would like to use `git-flow` here as I do for the rest of the projects with a normal branching scheme (meaning only one master) but in this case I have to main master branches and sometimes code goes to master or to web4_master or both. Is there any way to handle this by using `git-flow`? Or do I have to be tied to the old way meaning merging changes to wherever they go manually?

Comment: Do you maintain several concurrent versions of your software, such as a "v1.0" and a "v1.1"? If not, I would recommend not using git-flow at all. It's only useful when you need to maintain more than one version, such as continuing to support old versions of your software with security patches.

Comment: @meagar I do not mantain versions I will take note on your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `web4` includes all changes for the other sites, I would structure the repo as follows:

- One `master` branch as normal
- One `develop` branch from `master` as normal
- `web4_master` is a branch from `master`
- `web4_develop` is a branch from `web4_master`

If a feature is for all sites, then the work is done in a feature branch from `develop` like "normal" `git-flow`. Eventually, this will be ready for release and merged into `master`.

If a feature is just for `web4`, then the work is done in a feature branch from `web4_develop`, and eventually merged into `web4_master`.

Essentially, there are two `git-flow`s happening - one for all sites, and one for `web4` specific things.

The final piece:

During the release process for all sites (or whenever makes the most sense for you), `web4` needs to get the latest released changes.

1. Rebase `web4_master` on to `master`. Likely there will be conflicts here, so resolve them as needed
2. Rebase `web4_develop` on to `web4_master. This will NOT be a standard rebase and will need to make use of the`--onto` flag to avoid duplicating commits. See [this](https://coderwall.com/p/xzsr9g/rebasing-dependent-branches-with-git) for a detailed explanation
3. Repeat step 2 for any `web4` in-progress feature branches on to `web4_develop`.

Essentially, this is treating the `web4` tree as a long running feature branch from `master`.

---

I would not recommend this if there are a significant changes from the "all sites" features, or if the changes are very widespread, since the conflict resolution will get to be annoying.

In that instance, I would recommend the solution you had of manually merging changes to two root branches.

---

It is also possible that this approach makes sense / is easier using a merge strategy, but that's not my preference for something like this.